# bootstrap use mousedown instead of click or mouseup

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown, twitter-bootstrap-4

By default Bootstrap dropdown will listen to "mouseup" or "click" event, anyone has a good solution for Bootstrap dropdown using "mousedown" instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
 [Click Here to see how you can achive it.](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/pull/5430/commits/57b8d39addd39e29c42bb6bdd835e6521ab15d7c)

Comment: does not work on new bootstrap.js: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap

Comment: It is beta version. Why are you using bootstrap 4 in your projects.